# parent child relationship self join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `Event` model needs to have a self-referential join. Every event can belong to one other event. So there is **one** parent. An event can not belong to any other parents.

I read [the AR docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) on the subject, but for some reason keep getting stumped on what relation I should use in my model.

Any suggestions on what relation to use?

Comment: What is your problem with the self join in the link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about?

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Event', :foreign_key => :parent_id
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Event'
```

**Note:** You will have to add the column `parent_id` to the events table

Comment: In my case parents can only have one child, but I found I had to specify the foreign key in `has_one :child, :class_name => 'Event', :foreign_key => :parent_id` in order for it to work.

Comment: I get `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column events.event_id does not exist`, `LINE 1: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."event_id" = ...`. How do I make children join on just `id` and not `event_id`?