# How to eager load an association in the subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code :

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
   # attributes  name:string, root_id:integer , type:string , .....
   has_many :childrens, class_name: 'Children, foreign_key: :root_id, primary_key: :id
end
```

and another class Children with

```
class Children < Parent
   belongs_to :root, class_name: 'Parent', foreign_key: :root_id, primary_key: :id
end
```

`Parent` objects can be appear `multiple times` in the same table (*for some reason...*), but i wouldn't duplicate rows and copy all information each time, so i just make this `Children` subclass which inherit from `Parent`, and `root_id` is the `reference` to the parent, example :

```
object 1 :  { id: 1 , name: "parent object", root_id: nil, type: nil, .... }
object 2 : {id: 2, name: "child", root_id: 1, type: 'Children', ....}
object 3 : {id: 3, name: "child", root_id: 1, type: 'Children', ... }
```

then i do something like this :

```
Parent.where("id IN (2, 3)")
```

here i fetch just 'Children' objects, so i want to eager load their parent, to have access to the name, and also other attributes ...

i tried with this

```
Parent.where("id IN (2, 3)").includes(:root)
```

but i get this error :

```
Association named 'root' was not found on Parent; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

it seem that :root association from the subclass is not accessible in the Parent class, there is a way to improve performance ?

Comment: @Thahakp no because Children is a subclass of Parent when you do Parent.where("id In (2,3)") you are fetching records which type is 'Children' so you can't includes :chilrens for a children objects, i want the parent instead :)

Comment: You are inheriting one model to another. Try to avoid this by modifying the ER diagram.

Comment: Yes we call this Single Heritence Table, so have you a suggestion ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316559/parent-child-relationship-self-join

Answer (score 1):

Simple. The includes method takes on the associations that you have defined for a class. In your case, it takes only :childrens(it should actually be children without 's').

So to make available the :root to the includes method, cut and paste the belongs_to association from the Children(it should be actually be Child) class to the Parent class as below.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :childrens, class_name: 'Children, foreign_key: :root_id, primary_key: :id
   belongs_to :root, class_name: 'Parent', foreign_key: :root_id, primary_key: :id
end
```

Now, the following should work assuming, you dont have other problems.

```
Parent.where("id IN (2, 3)").includes(:root)
```

Tip:

```
1.9.3p385 :007 > "Child".pluralize
 => "Children" 
1.9.3p385 :008 > "Children".singularize
 => "Child"
```

Comment: yes you are right it works :) child or children is just a names i created for example, in reality i have Article which is the parent and Reshare which is a child, so an Article from a user can be reshared by his friends, what do you think about my solution ?